# Trying to get the previous and next item of an array using index

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, each

What I'm trying to do is to create a new array which from an input array and iterate through it. Each item of the new array is the result of the multiplication of the previous and next item of the iteration.

For example:

```
Array input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Array_final: [2, 3, 8, 15, 24, 30]
   first item: 2*1 (because there's no previous item)
   second item: 3*1
   third item: 4*2
   forth item: 5*3
   fifth item: 6*4
   sixth item: 6*5 (we use the current item because we don't have a next one)
```

This is my code and I don't understand why I keep getting array_final = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

```
class Arrays
      def self.multply(array)
        array_final = []
        last_index = array.length-1
      
        array.each_with_index do |num, i|
          if i == 0
            array_final.push (num[i+1])
          elsif i == last_index
            array_final.push (num*num[i-1])
          else
            array_final.push(num[i+1]*num[i-1])
          end
        end
        return array_final
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `num` as an array, when its an element.

I think you meant:

```
array.each_with_index do |num, i|
  if i == 0
    array_final.push (array[i+1])
  elsif i == last_index
    array_final.push (num*array[i-1])
  else
    array_final.push(array[i+1]*array[i-1])
  end
end
```

Comment: @KhaledJorbran: Your explanation is right, of course, but why isn't the indexing of an Integer (`num[i+1]`) an error? Indeed, I tried it in _irb_  and, i.. `1[1]` was excepted and returned 0. Stil, the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/) don't show the existence of a `[]` method for a number.

Comment: @user1934428 It exists it the `Integer` class, apparently it returns the bit value of that index, check it [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D). Thanks for your curiosity.. we learned something!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`each_cons`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_cons) to get sequential items:

```
final = [input[0] * input[1]]

input.each_cons(3) do |precedent, _current, subsequent|
  final << precedent * subsequent
end

final << input[-1] * input[-2]
```

[Live example](http://tpcg.io/usqv95mU)

Comment: Alternatively, drop `final = ...` and `final <<..` and write `[1,*input,1].each_cons(3) do |precedent, _current, subsequent|; final << precedent * subsequent; end`.